# Clientes , média passagens

Tags: oracle

=====usamos banco de dados oracle===============
Preciso adaptar a query para trazer a média de compras de clientes em dias e valor, a ultima compra e a previsão de compra com base na média de compra em dias e valor, comecei por esta query que peguei de um video youtube em firebird

OBS TENHO MAIS DE UMA EMPRESA NO BANCO DE DADOS

A média de dias seria nas seguintes condicoes :

Emissao Dias 05/03/2021 0
Descarta Primeira Compra pra Calculo Media
07/07/2021 124
(124=07/07/2021-05/03/2021)
03/11/2021 119
(119=03/11/2021-07/07/2021)
média = soma(124+119)/2=121 Emissao Dias

---

```
SELECT FROM
   SELECT A.COD_CLIENTE,
    (SELECT MAX(A1.COD_CLIENTE)
      FROM VENDAS A1
      WHERE A1.COD_CLIENTE=A.COD_CLIENTE
      AND A1.EMISSAO < A.EMISSAO
      
      ) ID_ANT
   
 FROM VENDAS A) A
              
   JOIN VENDAS ANT ON ANT.COD_CLIENTE =ID_ANT 
   JOIN VENDAS ATU ON ATU.COD_CLIENTE=A.COD_CLIENTE
```

Comment: Motta, obrigado por ter respondido. Mas média de dias seria nas seguintes condicoes Emissao        Dias 
05/03/2021 0    Descarta Primeira Compra pra Calculo Media
07/07/2021 124    (124=07/07/2021-05/03/2021)
03/11/2021 119    (119=03/11/2021-07/07/2021)
 média = soma(124+119)/2=121 Emissao Dias

Comment: Porque descarta a 1@ compra ?! Edite sua pergunta por favor explicando TODO o problema.  Cria um exemplo numérico      http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score -1):

Talvez uns "round" ou "trunc" estejam faltando , mas a ideia básica.Eu faria um previsão media - desvio e média + desvio , algo como
Média $100 , desvio $10 , a compra seria entre $90 e $110.

```
/*
média de compras de clientes em dias e valor, a ultima compra e a previsão de compra com base na média de compra em dias e valor, 
*/
select COD_CLIENTE,
       (max(emissao)-min(emissao)/count(*)) media_dias,--intervalo ÷ qtd
       round(avg(valor),2) media_compra,--media simples
       max(emssao) ult_compra,--maior dt compra
       sysdate+(max(emissao)-min(emissao)/count(*)) dt_prev_prox_compra,--hoje +x dias
       round(avg(valor),2) vl_previsto--aqui caberia um desvio padrao , +- gerando um intervalo
from vendas
group by COD_CLIENTE
```

Comment: Publique uma base no fiddle para validar.